# angular 5 project release

Tags: angular5, nanogallery

I'm using angular-cli and implemented nanogallery in my project,
now i'm going to build my project:
if i run

> ng build --prod

after uploading file to host it throws these errors in console:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: i is not a function R/</</<@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:148258
each@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:22422
R/</<@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:145805
R/<@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:145721
R@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:145629
h@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:108785
l@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:108322
r/this.initiateGallery2@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:237166
t.nanogallery2/i.init@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:263620
t.nanogallery2@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:263679
jQuery.fn.nanogallery2/<@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:271921
each@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:22422
each@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:21097
jQuery.fn.nanogallery2@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:271900
M4vW/j</l.prototype.loadBranches/</<@http://ankiweb.ir/4.1155fed864443988871c.chunk.js:1:19424
u@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:48959
r/</h<@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:49257
ZSR1/</</</u</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:19495
onInvokeTask@http://ankiweb.ir/main.36efe7b363f6a9952e89.bundle.js:1:603433
ZSR1/</</</u</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:19408
ZSR1/</</</i</e.prototype.runTask@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:14671
ZSR1/</</</c</e.invokeTask@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:20589
e/this.invoke<@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:20474
u/n.args[0]@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:35813
undefined



ERROR TypeError: "i is not a function"
Rhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:148258eachhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:22422Rhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:145805Rhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:145721Rhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:145629hhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:108785lhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:108322initiateGallery2http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:237166inithttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:263620nanogallery2http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:263679nanogallery2http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:271921eachhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:22422eachhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:21097nanogallery2http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:271900loadBrancheshttp://ankiweb.ir/4.1155fed864443988871c.chunk.js:1:19424uhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:48959hhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:49257invokeTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:19495onInvokeTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/main.36efe7b363f6a9952e89.bundle.js:1:603433invokeTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:19408runTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:14671invokeTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:20589invokehttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:204740http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:35813
```

> 

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: l.branches[u].gallery is undefined M4vW/j</l.prototype.loadBranches/</<@http://ankiweb.ir/4.1155fed864443988871c.chunk.js:1:19176
u@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:48959
r/</h<@http://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:49257
ZSR1/</</</u</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:19495
onInvokeTask@http://ankiweb.ir/main.36efe7b363f6a9952e89.bundle.js:1:603433
ZSR1/</</</u</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:19408
ZSR1/</</</i</e.prototype.runTask@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:14671
ZSR1/</</</c</e.invokeTask@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:20589
e/this.invoke<@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:20474
u/n.args[0]@http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:35813
undefined
```

> 

```
ERROR TypeError: "l.branches[u].gallery is undefined"
loadBrancheshttp://ankiweb.ir/4.1155fed864443988871c.chunk.js:1:19176uhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:48959hhttp://ankiweb.ir/scripts.0334935c44e8c4e6422d.bundle.js:1:49257invokeTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:19495onInvokeTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/main.36efe7b363f6a9952e89.bundle.js:1:603433invokeTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:19408runTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:14671invokeTaskhttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:20589invokehttp://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:204740http://ankiweb.ir/polyfills.d248127361c9f04ac793.bundle.js:1:35813
```

every thing work's correctly except "gallery"

but if i run

> ng build

every thing is ok include "Gallery"

any body know what's the problem!?

[image: expected behaviour]

[image: result of ng build -- prod]

thank you!

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @Nattrass hi i fixed the issue by changing priority of dependencies of my project, i'll add the priority for you in few minutes

Comment: @Nattrass "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "assets/gallery/jquery.nanogallery2.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
        "assets/js/splash.js",
        "assets/js/require.js"
      ]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this production issue by referencing the none minified versions of jquery and nanogallery in angular.json

so change this...

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/nanogallery2/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"
        ]
```

to this...

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/nanogallery2/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.js"
        ]
```

I don't understand why but the minification and bundling of the already minified nanogallery jquery plugin was causing this issue.